# Simple Palindrome

Tags: java, palindrome

I've tried different approaches to do this, and when I do this..

```
import java.util.*;
public class Palindrome {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
  Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

  System.out.print("Enter number");
  int number = in .nextInt();
  int first = number
  int middle = 0;
  int last = first;
  boolean isPalindrome = last == first;

  if (isPalindrome) {
   System.out.print("This is a palindrome");
  } else
   System.out.print("This is not a palindrome");
 }
}
```

it spits out "this is a palindrome". Mind you I can't use loops. Shouldn't this work?

It works when I do this...

```
import java.util.*;
public class Palindrome {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
  Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

  System.out.print("Enter number");
  int first = 1;
  int middle = 0;
  int last = 5;

  boolean isPalindrome = last == first;

  if (isPalindrome) {
   System.out.print("This is a palindrome");
  } else
   System.out.print("This is not a palindrome");
 }
}
```

It tells me if it's a palindrome or not...
So, it works on my end, but not the users end.

What am I missing

Comment: You should provide proper code. Also what kind of i/p you are expecting. Doing `last=first` and then `lass==first` doesn't make any sense.

Comment: I'll try to make  my code cleaner, but even without the boolean, it doesnt work.

Comment: ow is this different from the question your asked befpre https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52415524/simple-palindrome-detector

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, you are assigning the value of the input to your variable `first` then you assigned the value of `first` to the variable `last`. You declared your boolean as `isPalindrome = first==last` (*true*) which will always be true in this scenario that's why you get "This is a palindrome". On your second block of code which you said "works" is because you declared `first = 1` and `last = 5`, when you did `isPalindrome = first==last` (*false*) the value of the palindrome will always be false hence you get "This is not a palindrome" output.

I think what you need to do is rewrite your logic so you can elaborate the process you want to do. Feel free to ask a follow-up question.

Answer (score 0):

In the first one, the user enters a number which is assigned to `first`, then you set `last` to be a reference to `first`. Since the truth value of `isPalindrome` depends on whether `last == first`, it will always be true, since you coded it that way. However, this doesn't actually prove that the number is a palindrome, because for example if the user enters the number 56, the number 56056 is not a palindrome (reverse is 65065).

In the second program, `first` is always 1 and `last` is always 5, so since they are never equivalent the condition `last == first` will always be false.

What are you attempting to achieve with the programs? Neither one tests the user input to be a palindrome. Try writing psuedocode first, in the comments if you like.